# Creating .htaccess to remove extensions

Tags: .htaccess, web

I have got this code inside a file called .htaccess to remove the extensions in my urls.  I have tried both putting the .htaccess in the root folder but also the folder where the script is located, neither works.. anyone know why?

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ $1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use this if i where you, you should create dynamic URL's instead.

The error however is that you have not opend the RewriteEngine yet. Your should add:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

So your final file should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ $1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, probably something to do with the host..? I've tried several .htaccess files with different code to get rid of the extension but I guess it is namesco <--- never go with them